# Why are exceptions not caught in a Spring Reactive function?

Tags: spring-boot, exception, project-reactor

I am trying to catch an exception thrown when running a reactive function (this function returns a Mono. I am using code inspired by
information at the following URL:

```
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/project-reactor-error-handling-examples
```

I have a test application with the following function:

```
private Mono myMethod() {
   return Mono.error(new Exception("My error"));
}
```

The test code is fairly simple: I simply call the myMethod() function and seek to catch the error:

```
public void errorProcessor()
{
   Mono.defer(()-> myMethod())
       .doOnError(exe -> System.out.println("FAILURE! "+exe.getMessage());
       .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

What I was expecting was a printout of the failure message I specified. Instead, I am getting a stack trace!

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.Exception: My error
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: My error
    at net.factor3.apps.glucoseserv.control.GlucoseDataControllerTest.myMethod(GlucoseDataControllerTest.java:148) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at net.factor3.apps.glucoseserv.control.GlucoseDataControllerTest.lambda$0(GlucoseDataControllerTest.java:177) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4515) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4371) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4307) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4254) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
                              <the rest left ut for brevity>
```

I have debugged the errorProcessor() function, only to discover that the doOnError is not being called. None of what I am attempting to
print out is being printed out.This means that while the exception is being generated, it is not being caught.

Why is the doOnError() function not being called on error? How is it that an eception generated is not being properly caught? How does one actually catch and process
an exception in a Reactor- based function?

Comment: I would suggest checking the entire output to see if your `doOnError()` print statement in fact did get called...but perhaps not where you expected to see it.

Comment: Not sure what is your goal here but typically you should not call `subscribe` explicitly. But if you really need to it, provide a separate callback for error signal `.subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println)`

Comment: Alex: the goal here is to catch the exception and eliminate the stack trace, in a manner similar to the way a try- catch block would. That is why I created this test program. I wanted to create a case where an exception is thrown and caught by the calling function so I could see how the mechanism worked.

Comment: Tim: It looks like you were right. I was expecting my output to appear instead of the stack trace, but as it turns out I got both. My problem now is: how do I stop the stack trace and generate only the output?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that (1) when a failure occurs there is a stack trace printed out *and* the error message that I put in the doOnError() method is printed out. One can seldom tell, however, exactly when the message would be printed out.

(2) My goal for the test was to be able to process an "error" in a manner similar to the way a try- catch block does. I expected that using the doOnError() function would display my error message and eliminate the stack trace. I was incorrect.

What I needed to use in order to reach my goal was a variation of the subscribe() method, as shown below:

```
public void errorProcessor()
{
   Mono.defer(()-> myMethod())
      .subscribe(data->{
         System.out.println(data);
      },error->{
         System.out.println("FAILURE: "+error.getMessage());
      });
}
```

This subscribe variant "catches" the exception in the same way that a catch block does. It outputs my failure message and eliminates the stack trace.